# How to copy a large file between multiple servers?

Tags: algorithm, server

This is a linkedin interview question [here](https://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/How-to-copy-an-extremely-large-file-to-multiple-servers-in-the-system-quickly-and-efficiently-QTN_1633719.htm).

I can think of some sort of collaboration between servers. Example assume we treat servers like a tree:

1

2   3

4 5 6 7

Where server 1 copies to server 2 and 3, server 2 and 3 copy to to 4 and 5 etc.

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Use a FileStream of some sort.

Comment: You should post the related question instead/in addition to a Link.

Comment: Also consider some sort of compression because transmitting needs much more time than compressing (in most cases). If CPU-load is no issue I would always go for a compression before transmitting over a network.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough information in the question to narrow down the possible answers to the *best* one.

That provides you, the interviewee, with a great opportunity to mention all the things you know about that may be relevant considering the other parameters of the problem.

The interviewer really wants to hear about all the different ways you know of approaching this. You will get ++ points for discussing things that will really be relevant in certain situations (he will ask you about which situations its relevant in), and -- points for mentioning stuff that you've heard about if you have no idea whether or not or why it might be important.

You will probably also get -- points for thinking that you know the best answer without considering the situations in which it might not be best.  If you come up with an answer right away, he will ask you "why is that the best way if, say, ....", and you should have a good answer.  "Ah, I failed to consider that situation.  In that case..." is a good answer.

I interview a lot of candidates in my position, and I'm gonna start asking this question, too.

There's also a lot of fun follow-on questions I can use if the candidate gets through this business too fast, like "what if the downloads to the various servers are initiated by users on those servers and they don't all need the file at exactly the same time (but they will decide that they want it while you already have downloads in progress to others)," etc.

As a candidate, just remember: **the job is not a prize for getting the right answers**.

Comment: Sure, but I would also request you to provide some of your thoughts to approach this problem. Thanks

Comment: Haha...dicey !! :P